# Last name Fahnel pronunciation

Tags: grammar, pronunciation, person-names

Our last name is *Fahnel* which is German and I wanted to know the correct way to pronounce it. Some relatives believe it is pronounced *Fennel* like the spice but I believe it is either *Fah-nel* or *Fohnel.*

Answer (score 16):

Assuming that the spelling was unchanged upon immigration to the US, the pronunciation would be *Fah-nel* (IPA: [ˈfaːnəl]), with the *ah* pronounced like the sound your doctor asks you to make at a check up.

That said, *Fahnel* isn’t an extremely common German name, and it’s very possible that your ancestors left Germany as *Fähnels,* and then had their name “Americanized” by removing the umlaut (see for example *Müller → Muller/Muhler* etc.). This would be my bet. In that case, the original pronunciation was more akin to *fennel* but with the first vowel being long and stressed (IPA: [ˈfɛːnəl]).

<sup>[Here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:German_pronunciation) is a guide to the relevant IPA pronunciation for speakers of English.</sup>

Comment: I beliwve it was changer from faehnel.Dunno if that helps.Thanks much for the information.

Comment: @kenty5000 Faehnel = Fähnel, and in that case the second pronunciation is most definitely the original. If this has answered your question, please indicate this by accepting the answer.